# Determine whether JSON is a JSONObject or JSONArray

Tags: android, arrays, json, object

I am going to receive either a JSON Object or Array from server, but I have no idea which it will be. I need to work with the JSON, but to do so, I need to know if it is an Object or an Array.

I am working with Android.

Does any one have a good way of doing this?

Comment: If using Gson with Android and when it comes to deserialing one way to do it is like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52456821/6413377).

Answer (score 262, accepted):

I found better way to determine:

```
String data = "{ ... }";
Object json = new JSONTokener(data).nextValue();
if (json instanceof JSONObject)
  //you have an object
else if (json instanceof JSONArray)
  //you have an array
```

tokenizer is able to return more types: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html#nextValue()

Comment: nice job. hope it will check for both JsonObject and Json Array

Comment: @neworld but what if I am in the middle of a loop. trying to get a data.getJSONArray() or data.getJSONObject() will potentially throw a JSONEXception!!

Comment: Hi my objectdata is middle of response so how can i detect that? to check whether its a JSONObject or JSONArray???    and In your answer  String data = "{ ... }";    is  having value of whole response???

Comment: To accomplish that, you have to parse your JSON using `JSONTokener`. I didn't do that, but I suppose you should [skipPast("your_key")](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html#skipPast(java.lang.String)). But I am not sure. However, you should consider using json mapper: Gson, Jackson, Moshi and ton of others.

Answer (score 55):

There are a couple ways you can do this:

1. You can check the character at the first position of the String (after trimming away whitespace, as it is allowed in valid JSON).  If it is a `{`, you are dealing with a `JSONObject`, if it is a `[`, you are dealing with a `JSONArray`.
2. If you are dealing with JSON (an `Object`), then you can do an `instanceof` check.  `yourObject instanceof JSONObject`.  This will return true if yourObject is a JSONObject.  The same applies to JSONArray.

Comment: That definitely worked.

In the end though, I put the string into a JSONObject and if it threw an error, then I knew it was a JSONArray.

try {
 return new JSONObject(json);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
  
try {
 return new JSONArray(json);
} catch (Exception e) {
}

Answer (score 15):

This is the simple solution I'm using on Android:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

if (json.has("data")) {

    JSONObject dataObject = json.optJSONObject("data");

    if (dataObject != null) {

        //Do things with object.

    } else {

        JSONArray array = json.optJSONArray("data");

        //Do things with array
    }
} else {
    // Do nothing or throw exception if "data" is a mandatory field
}
```

Comment: Not Android specific and I like this version best because it uses no character checks, but the `json.has("data")` supposes the whole thing is optional (not asked for).

Answer (score 8):

Presenting an another way :

```
if(server_response.trim().charAt(0) == '[') {
    Log.e("Response is : " , "JSONArray");
} else if(server_response.trim().charAt(0) == '{') {
    Log.e("Response is : " , "JSONObject");
}
```

Here `server_response` is a response String coming from server

Answer (score 2):

A more fundamental way of doing this is the following.

`JsonArray` is inherently a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

`JsonObject` is inherently a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

```
if (object instanceof Map){
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.putAll((Map)object);
    ...
    ...
}
else if (object instanceof List){
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    jsonArray.addAll((List)object);
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Note, this does not work with org.json (not inherited from List or Map), works only with javax.json (jakarta.json-api). An approach here is to try an array, if it fails, catch and try object.

Answer (score 0):

instanceof

Object.getClass().getName()

Comment: I think the question assumes that you will be working with a plain string so using the instanceof or getClass().getName() wont work.

Comment: @gamerson -- That's odd -- it's worked for me many times.  You just have to have the parser return either object, vs specifying which.

Comment: Clearly folks don't understand this.  Pretty much every parser I've seen has a parse option to return a "JSONInstance" or simply "Object", or whatever.  Parse the JSON and then ask it what it is.  A parser which doesn't have this ability is broken.

Comment: (This is, in fact, Neworld's answer, more or less.)

Answer (score 0):

For those tackling this issue in JavaScript, the following did the job for me (not sure how efficient it is).

```
if(object.length != undefined) {
   console.log('Array found. Length is : ' + object.length); 
} else {
 console.log('Object found.'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonNode jsonNode=mapper.readTree(patchBody);
```

jsonNode has two method:
isObject();
isArray();

Answer (score -1):

My approach would be a total abstraction from this. Maybe someone finds this useful...

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class SimpleJSONObject extends JSONObject {


    private static final String FIELDNAME_NAME_VALUE_PAIRS = "nameValuePairs";


    public SimpleJSONObject(String string) throws JSONException {
        super(string);
    }


    public SimpleJSONObject(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {
        super(jsonObject.toString());
    }


    @Override
    public JSONObject getJSONObject(String name) throws JSONException {

        final JSONObject jsonObject = super.getJSONObject(name);

        return new SimpleJSONObject(jsonObject.toString());
    }


    @Override
    public JSONArray getJSONArray(String name) throws JSONException {

        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

        try {

            final Map<String, Object> map = this.getKeyValueMap();

            final Object value = map.get(name);

            jsonArray = this.evaluateJSONArray(name, value);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        }

        return jsonArray;
    }


    private JSONArray evaluateJSONArray(String name, final Object value) throws JSONException {

        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

        if (value instanceof JSONArray) {

            jsonArray = this.castToJSONArray(value);

        } else if (value instanceof JSONObject) {

            jsonArray = this.createCollectionWithOneElement(value);

        } else {

            jsonArray = super.getJSONArray(name);

        }
        return jsonArray;
    }


    private JSONArray createCollectionWithOneElement(final Object value) {

        final Collection<Object> collection = new ArrayList<Object>();
        collection.add(value);

        return (JSONArray) new JSONArray(collection);
    }


    private JSONArray castToJSONArray(final Object value) {
        return (JSONArray) value;
    }


    private Map<String, Object> getKeyValueMap() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {

        final Field declaredField = JSONObject.class.getDeclaredField(FIELDNAME_NAME_VALUE_PAIRS);
        declaredField.setAccessible(true);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) declaredField.get(this);

        return map;
    }


}
```

And now get rid of this behaviour forever...

```
...
JSONObject simpleJSONObject = new SimpleJSONObject(jsonObject);
...
```