# JSON Java check element is a JSONArray or JSONObject

Tags: java, android, web-services, json

How to check whether an element is a JSONArray or JSONObject. I wrote the code to check,

```
if(jsonObject.getJSONObject("Category").getClass().isArray()) {

} else {

}
```

In this case if the element 'category' is JSONObject then it work fine but if it contains an array then it throw exception: JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject. Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13100642/1318946 Check it.... May Helpful to you..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, this is because the `getJSONObject("category")` will try to convert that `String` to a JSONObject what which will throw a `JSONException`. You should do the following:

Check if that object is a `JSONObject` by using:

```
   JSONObject category=jsonObject.optJSONObject("Category");
```

which will return a `JSONObject` or `null` if the `category` object is not a json object.
Then you do the following:

```
   JSONArray categories;
   if(category == null)
        categories=jsonObject.optJSONArray("Category");
```

which will return your `JSONArray` or null if it is not a valid `JSONArray` .

Answer (score 21):

Even though you have got your answer, but still it can help other users...

```
 if (Law.get("LawSet") instanceof JSONObject)
 {
    JSONObject Lawset = Law.getJSONObject("LawSet");                        
 }
 else if (Law.get("LawSet") instanceof JSONArray)
{
    JSONArray Lawset = Law.getJSONArray("LawSet");
}
```

Here `Law` is other `JSONObject` and `LawSet` is the key which you want to find as `JSONObject or JSONArray`.

Comment: Thanks perfectly i should verified between object and array.. So got the solution!!!!! :)

Answer (score 10):

```
String data = "{ ... }";
Object json = new JSONTokener(data).nextValue();
if (json instanceof JSONObject)
  //you have an object
else if (json instanceof JSONArray)
  //you have an array
```

tokenizer is able to return more types: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html#nextValue()

Answer (score 0):

```
           if (element instanceof JSONObject) {

                Map<String, Object> map = json2Java.getMap(element
                        .toString());
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("Key=" + key + " JSONObject, Values="
                            + element);
                }
                for (Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        logger.debug(entry.getKey() + "/"
                                + entry.getValue());
                    }
                    jsonMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `instanceof` to check the type of the result that you get. Then you can handle it as you wish.