# Convert JSON String to JSON Array

Tags: java, json

Hello i call a service if it contains multiple objects it make list but when it contain only one object it return a single object not a list  [] are missing , actually i want to convert them into java class using gson but in case of single exception it throw exception but when it contain list it work fine i actually need to convert my single gSON string to array ,please help me  ..here is the string

```
    {
   "response":{
      "projects":{
         "project":{
            "ixWorkflow":1,
            "sEmail":"j.a@loxvo.com",
            "sPhone":"",
            "ixProject":2,
            "ixPersonOwner":2,
            "fDeleted":false,
            "sProject":"Project Default",
            "fInbox":true,
            "sPersonOwner":"junaid"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

i want it to be like same as

```
   {
   "response":{
      "projects":{
         "project":[
            {
               "ixWorkflow":1,
               "sEmail":"j.a@loxvo.com",
               "sPhone":"",
               "ixProject":6,
               "ixPersonOwner":2,
               "fDeleted":false,
               "sProject":"project 2",
               "fInbox":false,
               "sPersonOwner":"junaid"
            },
            {
               "ixWorkflow":1,
               "sEmail":"j.a@loxvo.com",
               "sPhone":"",
               "ixProject":2,
               "ixPersonOwner":2,
               "fDeleted":false,
               "sProject":"Project Default",
               "fInbox":true,
               "sPersonOwner":"junaid"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add more 'full stops' to your question. It seems more like reading a Virginia Woolf novel.

Comment: Please include the code you have tried.

Comment: Can you please include your code of parsing.

Comment: I second aquaraga's comment - please try and use punctuation, it will make your question easier to deciper.

Comment: You'd like to change "project" from a single element to an array?  Well, either edit the JSON source to do that, or read it in with a simple parser, navigate through the Maps to "project", and replace the value of "project" with the appropriate List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to https://stackoverflow.com/a/7284813/1105291

Please try below code before you pass json to Gson for object conversion, and please let me know if you get any error. Only posibility that I can see is exception at if.

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
    JSONObject projectsJsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response").getJSONObject("projects"); 
    if(projectsJsonObject.getJSONArray("project") == null)
    {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.put(projectsJsonObject.getJSONObject("project"));
        projectsJsonObject.put("project", jsonArray);

    }
    //Pass jsonObject to Gson
```

Comment: JSONObject["project"] is not a JSONArr it throw this exception

Comment: I used projectsJsonObject.optJSONArray("project") instead of projectsJsonObject.getJSONArray("project") == null Anyways rest was fine thanks alot

Comment: @JunaidAkhtar I was expecting exception but at other place, but I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Google Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject o = (JsonObject)parser.parse("{\"a\": \"A\"}");
```