# Method to cast Object to JSONObject or JSONArray depending on the Object

Tags: java, android, casting, json

I have been trying a method like this but I can't find any solution:

```
public static JSONObject or JSONArray objectToJSON(Object object){
    if(object is a JSONObject)
        return new JSONObject(object)
    if(object is a JSONArray)
        return new JSONArray(object)
}
```

I have tried this:

```
public static JSONObject objectToJSONObject(Object object){
    Object json = null;
    try {
        json = new JSONTokener(object.toString()).nextValue();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)json;
    return jsonObject;
}

public static JSONArray objectToJSONArray(Object object){
    Object json = null;
    try {
        json = new JSONTokener(object.toString()).nextValue();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONArray jsonObject = (JSONArray)json;
    return jsonObject;
}
```

But then when I invoke objectToJSONArray(object) I put a JSONObject it crashes casting. So I want a generic method. Someone find any solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume you've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118708/determine-whether-json-is-a-jsonobject-or-jsonarray).
You can probably just add a check of the type using `instanceof` before you return from each method, and return null if the Object is not of the type expected.  That should get rid of the ClassCastException.

Example:

```
public static JSONObject objectToJSONObject(Object object){
    Object json = null;
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        json = new JSONTokener(object.toString()).nextValue();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
        jsonObject = (JSONObject) json;
    }
    return jsonObject;
}

public static JSONArray objectToJSONArray(Object object){
    Object json = null;
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    try {
        json = new JSONTokener(object.toString()).nextValue();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (json instanceof JSONArray) {
        jsonArray = (JSONArray) json;
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
```

Then, you can try both methods, and use the return value of the one that doesn't return null, something like this:

```
public void processJSON(Object obj){
    JSONObject jsonObj = null;
    JSONArray jsonArr = null;
    jsonObj = objectToJSONObject(obj);
    jsonArr = objectToJSONArray(obj);
    if (jsonObj != null) {
        //process JSONObject
    } else if (jsonArr != null) {
        //process JSONArray
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`JsonArray` is inherently a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

`JsonObject` is inherently a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Since Java doesn't support functions having multiple return types(unless it is a generic function with return type accepted as argument - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/450874/820410)), the most simple way to perform what you need is the following:

```
if (object instanceof Map){
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.putAll((Map)object);
    ...
    ...
}
else if (object instanceof List){
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    jsonArray.addAll((List)object);
    ...
    ...
}
```

---

An alternative to this, if you want it as a function, is to convert the given `JsonObject` into a `JsonArray` and write your code to operate on that `JsonArray`, without having to worry about the type. The following function serves the said purpose.

```
public JSONArray getJsonObjectOrJsonArray(Object object){
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    if (object instanceof Map){
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.putAll((Map)object);
        jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
    }
    else if (object instanceof List){
        jsonArray.addAll((List)object);
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
```