# A value of a json str sometimes is a String, sometimes is a object, how could i use gson to parse it

Tags: android, json, gson

Like the title , my json str sometimes like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "changebaby": "no change",
        "changemama": {
            "mamacontext": "mama is a good mama",
            "mamaico": "",
            "mamatitle": "mama"
        }
    }
}
```

sometimes it like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "changebaby": "no change",
        "changemama": "no change"
    }
}
```

as you see,the value of the "changebaby" key and the "changemama" key sometimes is a String, sometimes is a object, how should i parse it by gson? Could anybody help me?

---

Don't use the android api to parse the json string, need to use the gson lib of google to parse the json string, could anybody help me?

Comment: Check with this [url](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13100642/2078074). Hope it helps you.

Comment: @Lawrance is right you have to check with `instanceof `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplyfy android development, we can ask for the backend developers to change the Mobile API.The new API could returen the json string that cann't change the value.The value of all keys cann't sometimes be a string, sometimes a object.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this :

```
JSONObject changemama=jsonObject.optJSONObject("changemama");
    if(changemama== null){
         String str=jsonObject.optString("changemama");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(jsonObject.optJSONObject("changemama") != null)
{
     JSONObject changemama=jsonObject.optJSONObject("changemama");
     //Its JSON object, do appropriate operation
}
else if(jsonObject.optString("changemama") != null)
{
     //Its string, do appropriate operation
}
```

if you have more number of possibilities like boolean or int or long, refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

**optJSONObject**

> Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONObject, or
>   null otherwise.

Or go with the way lawrance has given : [Determine whether JSON is a JSONObject or JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118708/determine-whether-json-is-a-jsonobject-or-jsonarray/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
JSONObject data;
try {
    data = jsonObj.getJSONObject("changemama");

    // do stuff

} catch (JSONException e) {
    data = jsonObj.getString("changemama");

    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: there are 50% possibilities for program to be crashed..!!

Comment: can you explain how?

Comment: Its is not guaranteed that the object will be string or JSONobject in it is none of them the program will be crashed use `optString` & `optJsonObject` instead..!!

Comment: in his case.. he was pretty sure he will be getting either of them. but anyways thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @vrundpurohit  no, in the json string, the value of changebaby and changemama is all not sure, they are possiblly a string or a object.

Comment: @vrundpurohit   The json string is getted from server, so we cann't be sure that the two property's value is a string or a object.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
if(obj.has("changemama")){
   if(obj.optString("changemama").length() > 0){}
   else if(obj.optJSONObject("changemama").length() > 0){}}
```