# Determine if an Object is an array or a string

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, android-json

I have some JSON data being returned from the server.

Sometimes the data is an Array other times, it returns an empty string (yes, I know it should return an empty array).
So I need to check FIRST if the type is an instance of a String; if so, I'm going to ignore it and go on with life.
Else I need to read in the values.

*How do I determine if an object is a `String`?*

I have looked at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118708/determine-whether-json-is-a-jsonobject-or-jsonarray) and some other, but I don't think it exactly fits my scenario.
I feel like I'm close, but my code fails denoting I can't cast an object to a string.
But if I cast it to a string... then it will ALWAYS be an instance of a string.   Infinite loop.

Here is where I am at so far.

```
private void myMethod(JSONObject data){
    if (data.has("Notes")){
        Object json = new JSONTokener(data.getJSONObject("Notes")).nextValue();

        if(data.getJSONObject("Notes") instanceof String) {
            JSONArray array = data.getJSONObject("Notes").getJSONArray("Note");
            //do all the array stuff
        }
    }
}
```

JSON with Array Example

```
{ "Data": {
        "key": "A value",
        "another key": "some value",
        "Notes": {
            "Note": ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
        } } }
```

JSON without Array Example

```
{ "Data": {
        "key": "A value",
        "another key": "some value",
        "Notes": ""
    } }
```

Comment: `getJSONObject` returns a `JSONObject`, which is not `instanceof String`

Comment: I need to know the what the contents of "Notes" is. Is it a string or is it an array?

Comment: I think you want `get("Notes") instanceof` since `get` is what returns the `Object` class. You could also try one of the `opt` methods that returns `null` when it cannot convert.

Answer (score 1):

You have this

```
Object json = new JSONTokener(data.getJSONObject("Notes")).nextValue();
```

But you aren't using `json` here. You've extracted out `getJSONObject("Notes")` a second time.

```
if(data.getJSONObject("Notes") instanceof String) {
```

Try

```
if(json instanceof String) {
```

---

If that doesn't work, I'd try

```
JSONObject notesObj = data.optJSONObject("Notes");
if (noteObj == null) {
    // It might be a string, but it was not an object
}
```

I'm not sure what would happen if you just used `getString("Notes")` against a value that was an object. It might `toString` it, but I haven't tried it recently to remember.