# Check JSON object in java

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2, jsonschema2pojo

I am fetching a JSON using retrofit 2, which carries object if the key has value else an empty array. ex:

> If the key i.e **address** has values it returns object

```
{
    "student": {
        "name": "Some name",
        "address": {
            "house": "5",
            "road": "3"
        }
    }
}
```

> If the key i.e **address** does not have any value it returns empty array

```
{
    "student": {
        "name": "Some name",
        "address": []
    }
}
```

In my POJO class I have made my Address class type to object so that retrofit can parse the JSON.

```
public class Student {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
private Object address;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public Object getAddress() {
return address;
}

public void setAddress(Object address) {
this.address = address;
}

}
```

Now how can I check that the **address** type is object or an array?

I have tried with isArray(), but did not find result.

```
if(obj.getclass().isArray())
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do this 
`(obj instanceof JSONObject)` or `(obj instanceof JSONArray)`

Comment: check if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/a/13100642/2116420

Answer (score 0):

You can check through `instanceof`  is object is `JosnObject` or `JsonArray`?

```
if (address instanceof JSONObject) {
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) address;
}
else  if (address instanceof JSONArray) {
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for json schema validation where you have to definie everything regrading type and format of json and later on validate your json using 
***Jackson 2.x libraries and fge/json-schema-validator.***

Reference link for more details.

http://wilddiary.com/validate-json-against-schema-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

*I wonder why your `json` is not consistent?* I mean if there is no value in address it not supposed to be a `JSONArray`

Instead it supposed to be like -

```
"address": {
    "house": "",
    "road": ""
}
```

It will easy to parse if you are doing like above - 
Now you `Pojo` will be -

```
public class Address {

@SerializedName("house")
@Expose
private String house;
@SerializedName("road")
@Expose
private String road;

public String getHouse() {
return house;
}

public void setHouse(String house) {
this.house = house;
}

public String getRoad() {
return road;
}

public void setRoad(String road) {
this.road = road;
}

}
```

And finally you can get the `Address` using -

```
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
private Address address;
```

in your `Student` class

**PS,

Server side problems must be fixed by Server side.**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. I have found my answer with the help of **instanceof**.
Instead of checking directly the **address** obj, I have to convert the value into Object type, i.e

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().setLenient().create();
String jsonStr = gson.toJson(obj.getAddress());
Object json = new JSONTokener(jsonStr).nextValue();
```

And then I can check with JSONObject

```
if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
 // Object
}else{
 // Array
}
```