# how to parse jsonobjects with same name inside jsonarray in android?

Tags: android, arrays, json

```
{
    "terms": [{
        "offset": 0,
        "value": "Nerkundram"
    }, {
        "offset": 12,
        "value": "Chennai"
    }, {
        "offset": 21,
        "value": "Tamil Nadu"
    }, {
        "offset": 33,
        "value": "India"
    }]
}
```

Comment: study this example http://www.journaldev.com/2321/gson-example-tutorial-parse-json

Comment: #Chandana_Raj This type of question already asked on here .Before asking question search on Google

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118708/determine-whether-json-is-a-jsonobject-or-jsonarray?rq=1

Comment: oops sorry @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: @Chandana_Raj for what ?

Comment: for asking question without searching it on google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
try{
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("terms");
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
     JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     String offset = object.getString("offset");
     String value = object.getString("value");
     //rest of the strings..
    }
 }
 catch (JSONException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @rafsanahmad007

Comment: if the answer helps mark it as correct by clicking the tick sign on left of the answer...thankx.@Chandana_Raj