# JsonNode Get Key from Value Using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an array which has 3  JsonNodes.
I managed to print the JsonNode that I want (which is an array)

```
Key: modelInformation
Value:[{"projectName":"Jum","modelName":"Jum01","modelId":"122"}}
```

Unfortunaly it looks like it merged the values together. How do I separate the key from the value in the Value section?

For example

```
Key: projectname
Value: Jum
```

`field.getKey()` or `field.getValue()` dosent work!
Key is `modelInformation`
and value is:

```
[{"projectName":"Jum","modelName":"Jum01","modelId":"122"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should treat the `Value` of you json object as a new `JSONObject`, which is already the case. Or more, the value in your case is an array of Json Objects.

So you can use:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(field.getValue());
```

Or if you are not sure if it's an array or an object, please take a look on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118708/determine-whether-json-is-a-jsonobject-or-jsonarray).