# Converting Blank Json Array to blank json object

Tags: android, json

My Json Object :

```
 "feedback_details":{
"id":"80",
"lead_id":"86075",
"account_id":"1543",
"document_id":"582348",
"reason_id":"4",
"description":"COAPPL_profile1.jpg",
"sales_remark":null,
"lat":"",
"long":"",
"status":"2",
"created_at":"2018-02-27 12:29:59",
"updated_at":"2018-02-27 12:29:59"
}
```

When i have no details in feedback_details then it comes to an empty json array like this :

```
"feedback_details":[
]
```

So i tried converting it forcefully to a blank json object :

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < object.getJSONArray("applicantPhoto").length(); j++) {
                object.getJSONArray("applicantPhoto").getJSONObject(j);
                if (object.getJSONArray("applicantPhoto").getJSONObject(j).optJSONObject("feedback_details") == null) {
                    new JSONObject(object.getJSONArray("applicantPhoto").getJSONObject(j).getString("feedback_details"));
                }
                if (object.getJSONArray("applicantSignatire").getJSONObject(j).optJSONObject("feedback_details") == null) {
                    String newstring = object.getJSONArray("applicantSignatire").getJSONObject(j).getJSONArray("feedback_details").toString();
                    //here i get the exception for type mismatch where the string is "[]"
                    new JSONObject(newstring);
                }
                if (object.getJSONArray("applicantPhoto").getJSONObject(j).optJSONObject("feedback_details") == null) {
                    new JSONObject(String.valueOf(object.getJSONArray("applicantPhoto").getJSONObject(j).getJSONArray("feedback_details")));
                }
            }
            Utility.printMessage("Json object..." + object);
```

I know that string is "[]", hence it showing an exception as Cannot be converted to JsonObject.
Can anyone suggest how to handle this, basically i need an empty object instead of that blank array.

Comment: You can check solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118708/determine-whether-json-is-a-jsonobject-or-jsonarray

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code

```
if(!object.getJSONArray("applicantPhoto").getJSONObject(j).isNull("feedback_details")) {
        if (object.getJSONArray("applicantPhoto").getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("feedback_details").toString().length() > 2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < object.getJSONArray("applicantPhoto").getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("feedback_details").length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = object.getJSONArray("applicantPhoto").getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("feedback_details").getJSONObject(i);
                //Get the Values of Feedback_details Key
            }
        } else {
            //Feedback_detail key is empty
        }
    } else {
        //Key is null or Array is empty
    }
```

Comment: I just need to convert that blank array to a blank object because i am doing Json parsing using gson so currently it is showing me a exception for type mismatch in gson, hence i need to convert this blank array to a blank obect before passing it to my gson

Comment: I'm editing my code.Please check it and try it again.

Comment: Can't get it @saurabh

Comment: tell me the issue?