# Generic solution to GSON json object Array with a key

Tags: java, json, generics, gson

I am trying to find a generic solution in GSON for my project. This JSON has been problematic for me...

I have a class System

```
public class System{
   String systemid;
   String systemname;
   //getter and setter
}
```

Rest service sends data in one of two below format, now for the second format I am handling it in a generic way as shown in last, can someone please help me to handle both the formats in a generic way in one piece of code, I am stuck on this from past two days now...

```
[
{
    "atypes": [
        {
            "systemid": "123",
            "systemname": "abc"
        },
        {
            "systemid": "456",
            "systemname": "def"
        },
        {
            "systemid": "789",
            "systemname": "ghi"
        },
        {
            "id": "0123",
            "name": "klm"
        },
        {
            "systemid": "4567",
            "systemname": "nop"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Or the second format

```
[
        {
            "systemid": "123",
            "systemname": "abc"
        },
        {
            "systemid": "456",
            "systemname": "def"
        },
        {
            "systemid": "789",
            "systemname": "ghi"
        },
        {
            "id": "0123",
            "name": "klm"
        },
        {
            "systemid": "4567",
            "systemname": "nop"
        }
]
```

Now I am handling the last JSON array in the below method, I want to handle both the code in one piece of generic code.

```
String data = client.executeCommand(Command.GET, new GenericUrl(URL), null);
    System[] tList1 = JsonUtil.jsonArrayToObjectArray(data, System[].class);
```

which calls a generic piece of code

```
public static <T> T[] jsonArrayToObjectArray(String data, Class<T[]> tClass) throws Exception {

    return new Gson().fromJson(data, tClass);

}
```

Please if someone can help me...

Edit:
This is different from identifying Json object and json array as here both are json array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine whether JSON is a JSONObject or JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118708/determine-whether-json-is-a-jsonobject-or-jsonarray)

Comment: Not a duplicate of this article, I know how to differentiate between JSONArray and JSON Object. Here the situation is different, both are a JSON array.